# why is it so hard to overwrite react mui styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I need to change `color/border-color` and so on in mui I just can't do it quickly.

I have a few Fields and Select components from MUI and they all have property `error={}` and I just want to change border or outline color when there is an error but I can't do it. I can't remove the initial border/outline and write my own. I tried to overwrite border-color but I can't do it.

```
<Select
      displayEmpty
      disabled={isEditMode}
      renderValue={() => renderClientValue()}
      {...registerFormikTextField('field', formik)}
      error={!clientId}
      helperText=" "
      value={clientId || ''}
    >
      {clients.map((client) => (
        <MenuItem key={client.id} value={client.id}>
          <ListItemText title={client.email} primary={client.email} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
```

I tried changing .Mui-error, use makeStyles but as I understood it is deprecated in latest version. I inspected the code and couldn't find where they put `border-color: red` as default style when we have an error={true}

How can I do it? Why should we use mui over tailwindcss/sass when I can't easily change the styles?

Comment: Look at `palette.error`: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/

Comment: "Why should we use mui over tailwindcss/sass when I can't easily change the styles?"  

MUI is more catered to apps that want prebuilt components that allows for customization. Tailwind is more so catered to building out highly customized components to then be used throughout the app.  

I chose MUI specifically because I did not want to build out every single component from scratch, it made much more sense for our application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass custom style to `Select` component through `sx` prop like this:

```
sx={{
    "&.Mui-error fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "red"
    }
}}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-error-0dk81f?file=/demo.tsx) for a live working example of this approach.